# Disable csrf when express route is called internally

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf

I have the following simple code to enable csrf protection

```
import csrf from 'csurf';

const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  },
});


app.use(csrfProtection);
```

Which means all app routes are using the middleware, and

```
router.get('/auth/csrf', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
});
```

has to be called first before making a request to this server.

Now, I have another backend microservice that is making API calls to one endpoint, and I dont want to enable the csrf check when it's the backend service calling the endpoint. But want to keep the checks if it is coming from elsewhere.

What approach would work for my case?

Comment: CSRF is there for protection against bots. If you put a backdoor for a particular bot (a.k.a your backend service) then you weaken your protection against other bots too.

Comment: IP whitelists are a possible way to do this. It's very common for websites to whitelist Googlebot's IP addresses (and other well-known bots) so that they can be crawled, but still block other bot traffic, for example

Answer (score 1):

If you really need CSRF in your application then you probably shouldn't disable it. With that said, you can use a custom middleware to have optional CSRF for your routes:

```js
import csrf from 'csurf';

const csrfProtection = csrf({
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  },
});

function optionalCSRF(req, res, next) {
  if (req.query.disableCSRF === 'true') {
    return next();
  }

  csrfProtection(req, res, next);
}

app.use(optionalCSRF);
```

Comment: so if I should not disable it, how can provide csrf while making that the internal request?
Does it make sense to have some predefined values that the service can use?

Comment: I'm not highly experienced with public-facing applications but some ideas are coming to my mind. You can come up with a way that your backend service(s) generate their own tokens for each request (and store them somewehere accesible by your API service) and your API service can validate tokens if they're provided.

Comment: You can remove CSRF and add Google's reCaptcha instead? This would be way more secure. But of course this doesn't answer how to identify your own backend service :)